# Различия в обработке скрипта PowerShell при запуске вручную и программно из C#

Tags: c#, powershell, sharepoint

Делаю автоматическую установку решения в SharePoint, пошел по самому простому, как мне казалось, пути: 
 
распаковываю PowerShell скрипт, решение и .cmd из embedded ресурсов в .exe,
 
вызываю запуск .cmd.

При запуске вручную все работает, при вызове из собранного .exe - не видит оснасток SP. Упростил задачу до вызова ТОЛЬКО PowerShell из C# - и вот здесь непонятное для меня :

add-pssnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell 

Оснастка microsoft.sharepoint.powershell Windows PowerShell не установлена на данном компьютере.

При этом в соседнем окошке PowerShell эта же команда спокойно отрабатывает.

Пользователь одинаковый (проверял командами), профиль (ныне пустой) тоже ведет в один файл при попытке вызова notepad $profile (была надежда туда добавить подключение снапина, не помогло). Что можно сделать?

Если это важно, запуск PS (а до этого .cmd) делаю через процесс:

`var process = new ProcessStartInfo();
 process.FileName = "powershell.exe";
 Process.Start(process).WaitForExit();`

[image: Одна команда в разных окнах]

Comment: попробуйте запустить установку от имени Администратора.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил. Для совпадения поведения PS надо сменить цель сборки на CPU x64 в Visual Studio. Кому интересно, почему - предлагаю пройти весь этот путь по крупинкам со всех источников )), но ответ именно таков.

Comment: Не понятно чему вы удивились, изначально проект в VS создается на базе x32, а не x64...а SP это только x64, в редких случаях можно попробовать прикрутить сервис с x32, но не без гемороя...

Comment: Ну, "Any CPU" я вообще не привык менять... Что же до знаний о том, что "SP - это x64", то ситуация в моем случае выглядела приблизительно так: "Для чего-чего надо написать автоинсталлятор? SharePoint? Project? Не, почему, что-то слышал... А почему это в  .cmd сразу не запихать? А-а-а...Ну, ладно..." :)))